# How do I add a carousel on Google Sites?

Tags: slider, carousel

What I'm trying to achieve is to create an eye catching carousel. The one currently used on Google sites isn't to my liking. I used the below code for a logo carousel, but I want only images. I'm new to coding and need help from more experienced coders who know exactly what to do and why? I want to understand what I'm doing. I will appreciate all the help I can receive on this issue. Thank you in advance.

```css
<div class=”container”>
    <!--<h2> Our Partners/ Our Clients</h2> →
    <section class=”customer-logos slider”>
        <div class=”slide”><img src=”link”</div>
        <div class=”slide”><img src=”link”</div>
        <div class=”slide”><img src=”link”</div>
        <div class=”slide”><img src=”link”</div>
        <div class=”slide”><img src=”link”</div>
        <div class=”slide”><img src=”link”</div>
        <div class=”slide”><img src=”link”</div>
        <div class=”slide”><img src=”link”</div>
        <div class=”slide”><img src=”link”</div>
        <div class=”slide”><img src=”link”</div>
    </section>
</div>
    <script>
        $ (document) .ready(function){
    $ (‘ .customer-logos’) .slick ({
        slicktoshow: 4;
        slidestoscroll: 1;
        autoplay: true;
        autoplayspeed: 1500;
        arrows: false;
        dots: false;
        pauseonhover: false;
        responsive: [{
            Breakpoint: 768;
            settings: {
                slidestoshow: 4;
                }
            }]
        }];
    }];
    </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href:”//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/boostrap.min.css” rel=”stylesheet” id=”bootstrap-css>
<script src=”//madcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootsrap.min.js”</script>
<script src=”//cdnjs.cloudfare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js”></script>
<script src=”https://cdnjs.cloudfare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js”></script>
<style>
body{
    overflow: hidden;
}
    h2{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
}
 / * Slider */
.slick-slider {

}
.slick-slider img{
    width:  100%;
}
.slick-slider
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -Khtml-user-select: none;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
        touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
.slick-list
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.slick-list: focus
{
    outline:none;
}
.slick-list .dragging
{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}
.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -moz-tranform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -0-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
.slick-track
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
}
.slick-track: before;
.slick-track: after;
{
    display:table;
    content: “”;
}
.slick-track: after
{
    clear: both;
}
.slick-loading .slick-track
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.slick-verticial .slick-slide
{
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    border: 1 px solid transparent;
}
.slick-arrow .slick-hidden{
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class=”container”>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: consider adding some code snippets if you have already started working on this. if not, best to start with the google sites tutorial, try a few things, come back when you get stuck. https://support.google.com/sites/answer/6372878?hl=en

Comment: Bill, you are new, so I am sure this is confusing. 1) edit your question, and you put your code in a code block. 2) use the comments for replying to me and other community members :)

Comment: Yes, it's very confusing and all new to me. I did edit my question and put my code that I used. But, I want to add images instead of logos.

Comment: yeah, its alright. we are here to help. Okay, so, can you try running your code on code sandbox? if you are new to code sandbox, this is a good time to start using it. http://codesandbox.io/  Also, this entire code does not run. I don't think this is the full code. I am trying to put it in a codesandbox, but I am getting so many errors.

Comment: What do I do? How do I run it on sandbox? It's all new to me.

Comment: visit the website and create a new account. they will give you some tour/help guides